# Implementing Isotope with Infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I have set up a basic example of isotope with the Infinitescroll plugin. 
It is seemingly working, but in fact it doesn't load anything from the next page. The second page is the exact copy of the index file. If I change the href of the nav to a nonexisting file, the console drops an error. Can you please help me out? Thanks!

```
var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.grid-item'

  });

 $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
            nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
            itemSelector : '.grid-item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
              }
            },
            // call Isotope as a callback
            function( newElements ) {

              $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
            }
          );

    <nav id="page_nav">
        <a href="pages/2.html"></a>
      </nav>


<div id="container" class="grid">
<div class="grid-item grid-item-box"></div>
......
</div>
```

Comment: Need to see your html. Especially your "#page_nav a". How about a codepen or a link?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZZMXJ